# Requiring the same module twice in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to write a serverless function to get and set data on FaunaDB. The problem is, FaunaDB throws an error if a try to create a collection with a name that already exists. So, before getting or setting the data, I first need o check if a collection exists, and create it if it doesn't.

So, I've my setup like this:

`setupFauna.js`:

```js
const faunaDB = require('faunadb')

module.exports = async function setupFauna(secret, collectionName) {

  const requiredDB = new faunaDB.Client({
    secret: secret
  })

}

// rest of the code
```

`functions/setData.js` and `functions/getData.js`:

```js
const faunaDB = require('faunadb')
const setupFauna = require('../setupFauna')

const faunaSecret = process.env.FAUNADB

const requiredDB = new faunaDB.Client({
  secret: faunaSecret
})

exports.handler = async () => {

  return setupFauna(faunaSecret, collectionName).then(() => {

    // rest of the code

  }

}
```

`setData.js` and `getData.js` are independent of each other and thus, they require the independent import of FaunaDB module. Both of them need the FaunaDB module in the rest of the code. However, since both of them depend on `setupFauna.js` which is already importing the same Node Module, is there a way to avoid the duplication of import? I'm not sure if what I'm doing is correct or not. From my understanding, I'm basically importing the same thing twice in the resultant `setData.js` and `getData.js`. Also, I'm having to configure the FaunaDB client in all these 3 files. This does seem error prone to me.

Can someone confirm if what I've currently setup is a good way to go or is there something I can do to make this optimal? Is importing the same thing multiple times a good idea? I understand it's not a problem when you require the same thing multiple times in the same file, but does that stand true for my case too?

Comment: Importing the same thing multiple times should have no effect, because loaded modules are cached.

Comment: Require has a cache that basically imports just once and then reuse already imported object for future imports.

Comment: To see for yourself, inspect the `require.cache` variable before and after imports. If you actually wanted to reload a module, you could remove the initial entry from `require.cache`.

Comment: To avoid multiple initializations, you should create a new module which performs the initialization and export an initialized `requiredDB` from this class.

Comment: @h0r53 I think this is what I'm looking for. Do you have any pointers as to how exactly I can do that?

Comment: @h0r53 Nevermind, turns out I figured it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From all the comments, it seems like it's not really required, but to simplify the process and make it less error-prone, I followed @hor53's comment and created another export.

So now I've my files like this:

`setupFauna.js`:

```js
const faunaDB = require('faunadb')

const requiredDB = new faunaDB.Client({
  secret: process.env.FAUNADB
})

async function setupFauna(collectionName) {

  // rest of the code

}

module.exports = {
  faunaDB,
  requiredDB,
  setupFauna
}
```

`functions/setData.js` and `functions/getData.js`:

```js
const faunaDB = require('../setupFauna').faunaDB
const commentsDB = require('../setupFauna').requiredDB
const setupComments = require('../setupFauna').setupFauna

exports.handler = async () => {

  return setupFauna(collectionName).then(() => {

    // rest of the code

  }

}
```

I'd be up to know if there's a better process or if I've missed something.

Comment: This seems like the right approach to me. Is it working well?

Comment: Yes, it's working perfectly, thanks @h0r53.